# How to set Holo light theme for all android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I accidentally did something in the layout and now all of my activities are dark colored with white text "inside TextViews", before that all of them were grey color with black text, as I searched the internet I believe that I somehow changed all activities from "Holo light" to "Holo dark", how can I get the default theme back?

PS. I don't believe the problem is from the layouts because I didn't touch them.
PS. Here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.excellence.youniversity"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/blue"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CoursesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_courses"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Technology"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_technology"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Science"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_science"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Langauges"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_langauges"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Thinking"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thinking"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Art"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_art"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Medicine"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_medicine"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RoboticActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_robotic"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TechActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tech"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WedooActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wedoo"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroiddActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_androidd"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CSIActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_csi"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChemistryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chemistry"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AstronomyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_astronomy"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ArchitectureActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_architecture"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AstronomyyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_astronomyy"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FashionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fashion"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhotographyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photography"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_video"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EnglishActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_english"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChessActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chess"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BudActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bud"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstaidActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_firstaid"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the Styles.xml inside the values folder

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Post your AppTheme file

Comment: I'm sorry for not fully understanding the question, do you mean the "Styles.xml" that are inside the values folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in your activities and that style will give you Holo Dark theme.

You have to replace that with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```